# How to run more than one scenario in a given feature file

Tags: karate

I'm able to find how to run single scenario under a given feature file. But not able to find any option to run multiple scenarios.

```
mvn test "-Dkarate.options=src/test/features/covid19-data.feature:7" -DargLine='-Dkarate.env=E1' -Dtest=ToolRunner
```

Answer (score 0):

I think multiple feature paths are supported delimited by the space character, but please contribute code or documentation if needed.

The standard answer is to use tags: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#tags

```
@one
Scenario:
* print 'first'

@one
Scenario:
* print 'second'
```

And in the command:

```
"-Dkarate.options=--tags @one src/test/features/covid19-data.feature"
```